# Getting error The 'proprrty1' property on 'table1' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. in my mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am getting an error in my mvc application. I am trying to display record  from my sql table using entity framework. here is the code which i am trying. But I dnt know why this code giving me error

This is my model

```
 [Table("tbInsertMobile")]
    public class tbInsertMobile
    {
        [Key]
        public int MobileID { get; set; }
        public string MobileName { get; set; }
        public string MobileIMEno { get; set; }
        public string mobileprice { get; set; }
        public string mobileManufacured { get; set; }

    }
```

my another class in model

```
public class EmployeeContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<tbInsertMobile> usermobiles { get; set; }
    }
```

This the code of my contoller

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            tbInsertMobile employee = employeeContext.usermobiles.Single(x => x.MobileID == id);

            return View(employee);
        }
```

and now the error which i am getting is this

```
The 'MobileID' property on 'tbInsertMobile' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32
```

Experts Tell me where I am getting this error
Thanks

Comment: It's trying to assign a `long` to an `int`. Change `MobileID` to be `long`.

Comment: okk it's gone but now i am trying to fetch record without view. but now its giving me error of view missing .. Now why this error comes? @CodeCaster

Comment: Because your view is missing.

Comment: yeaah i know it but i want to do this process without view @CodeCaster

Comment: You _are_ using a view: `return View(employee)` is trying to find a view called 'Index'

Comment: return another thing, if you don't want to return a View... A RedirectRouteResult, a JsonResult, whatever

Answer (score 1):

The answer is there already in the comment.

```
It's trying to assign a long to an int. Change MobileID to be long. –  CodeCaster
```